# Database design for a multiple choice question website

Tags: mysql, database-design, php, phpmyadmin

So I want to design a database schema for MCQ website in which I have several sections ,Lets say 3. and these section will have many sub-sections each. I want to store the questions, choices and correct ans in such a way that every questions of sub-topics get stored in same table but questions of different section`s sub-section get stored in different one.

but,I don't know how to design a database schema like this. or what else could be better Approach ?

Comment: Start by defining what the "Entities" are in your dataset.  Then define the "Relationships".